# init() function not run when importing cgo, with import "C"

Tags: go, init, cgo

If I import cgo into a go program, the init function does not appear to run.   This behaviour seems new, in that an (unspecified) older version of go did manage to run init().

The program is split into several go files, all in package main.  Most of these other files have an init function, which does this:

```
31 func init() {
 32   if len(testFunctionsMap) == 0 {
 33     testFunctionsMap = make(funcPtrMap)
 34   }
 35   testFunctionsMap["somename"] = funcname
 36   initCtr++
 37 }
```

I've added the initCtr (global) variable to keep track of how many init functions are called; the only one not called is the one in the file where I import "C" (with the concomitant special comments)

Comment: Are you sure none of the other `init()` functions block nor do they launch other goroutines that might concurrently access `testFunctionsMap` or `initCtr`?

Comment: Thanks @icza - user error - see answer just coming...

Answer (score 2):

It seems that it added this:
  CGO_ENABLED=0 ... go build ...
in the build script.  Unsurprising, then that the cgo init function didn't run - nor did anything else in that file, but I never got that far!